# Mint NFT and FT tokens in same transaction

Tags: mint

Is it possible to mint NFT and FT using same policyID and in the same transaction ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this.

The policy doesn't prevent this. The policy is used as a mechanism to prove that the tokens are really issued by the correct entity. E.g. I can't create a second HOSKY token with a different policy and pretend it's the real thing.

You can mint multiple different tokens in one transaction. The only difference between an NFT and an FT is that there should only be 1 of each NFT while there can be more than 1 of any particular FT.

As an example, let's look at the mint transaction of the berry NFTs, 50 NFTs were minted in one transaction. You could simply change the metadata and mint multiple of one of the tokens and you have your FT along with some NFTs: https://cexplorer.io/tx/10d3d8ffd9faf14ebfa57e999a9c448972f21ccbae0bcf9f3cd0ab1240870a6e